# Who is Rose Gonzalez? And what about contact owner ship?

Tags: salesforce1-app

If I run

```
SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID FROM Contact
```

in the developer console, I get

[image]

I assume that most of these contacts (except Tom Jones who I added) are default test data added to my DEV account?

However, if I go to the Salesforce1 app and go to the Contacts page, I only see Tom Jones.

Since they all have the same OwnerID, why don't I see the other contacts from  Salesforce1?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Salesforce1 only shows you recent items; here's the default view:

[image: recent-items]

After you choose a new view, you'll get more records on the screen:

[image: all-items]

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce1 shows recent visited contact list view on load. If you will search for any specific contact in Salesforce1 that new contact will appear and if you will open Salesforce1 app again you will see that contact in your list view with Tome Jones.

Comment: Yes, I realise now that it was only showing New Contacts - thanks